# Opensource alternative of DynDNS?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, dyndns, dynamic-dns

In the network where I work we have frequent situations where people setup a virtual to try something new out and want to tell others (within the same network) about their experiments.

For this kind of situation I would like to introduce an additional (sub)domain and let these people hook a hostname to their virtual similar to what internet based services like DynDNS do. I.e. the virtuals have a script that periodically updates their dns entry as they may have gotten a new IP from the internal DHCP server.

So far I've been unable to find a 'ready to run' opensource solution (for me it should run on Linux)  that can simply be installed on the LAN. (I'm probably no using the the right search terms.)

I did find this http://nexus.zteo.com/blog/your-own-dynamic-dns-in-3-steps/ but that requires giving the key to update the entire domain to everyone in the LAN.

What solutions have I missed ? 
Or writing up my own implementation the real way to go?

Comment: I think you missed `nsupdate`.

Comment: Permit unathenticated updates, then you don't have to give out a key.

Comment: From Bind 9.9 you don't even need to use `nsupdate` anymore; just define the zone as dynamic.

Answer (score -1):

This is the way to go for you, you won't need any keys.
You do need to setup all the clients in the network to use this internal DNS by giving it's IP.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=236093

Comment: This post simply describes how to setup a DNS server using BIND. Where is the DynDNS-like functionality? Things like automatic updating of the DNS triggered by a clientside script.

Comment: Maybe this: http://gnudip2.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look. The project seems quite dead. As far as I can tell the latest code update is about 12 years old.

Comment: It should still work tho, hope it still works with the newer versions of Perl but that is what you will have to find out yourself.